# How to enable stacktrace of JDBC Logging with ojdbc8_g.jar

Tags: java, sql, oracle, logging, jdbc

i have a problem regarding the activation of stack trace logging with ojdbc8_g.jar. While with ojdbc7_g.jar it is there and visible for each SQL statements executed, in the ojdbc8_g I didn't succeed to activate it. The only information that I got is the SQL statements, but I need also the stack trace one. I did search through the oracle documentation but could not find any indication of how to retrieve the stack trace from the 8 version. Anyone know if it is possible to get this information with ojdbc8_g?

Update:I'll add some detailed information
One simple class that execute one query on Oracle Database using this configuration: Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Workpath/java/log.properties -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true
Results with ojdbc7_g.jar are:

```
<record>
  <date>2020-04-08T10:39:39</date>
  <millis>1586335179544</millis>
  <sequence>19</sequence>
  <logger>oracle.jdbc.driver</logger>
  <level>CONFIG</level>
  <class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement</class>
  <method>doExecuteWithTimeout</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>674BD420 SQL: SELECT * FROM v_server</message>
  <exception>
    <message>java.lang.Throwable: No Error</message>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement</class>
      <method>doExecuteWithTimeout</method>
      <line>1427</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement</class>
      <method>executeQuery</method>
      <line>1795</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper</class>
      <method>executeQuery</method>
      <line>1513</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>it.igs.JDBCTest</class>
      <method>getSqlDirect</method>
      <line>96</line>
    </frame>
    <frame>
      <class>it.igs.JDBCTest</class>
      <method>main</method>
      <line>23</line>
    </frame>
  </exception>
</record>
```

If run the same test using the ojdbc8_g.jar the results are:

```
<record>
  <date>2020-04-08T10:39:39</date>
  <millis>1587367077619</millis>
  <sequence>19</sequence>
  <logger>oracle.jdbc</logger>
  <level>CONFIG</level>
  <class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement</class>
  <method>logSQL</method>
  <thread>1</thread>
  <message>142EEF62 SQL: SELECT * FROM v_server</message>
</record>
```

The properties file is the same that is used for generate the log, as you see in last test is missing the stack trace

Update 2: other informations about property file used.

```
level=SEVERE
oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.driver.level=CONFIG
oracle.jdbc.pool.level=SEVERE
oracle.jdbc.util.level=SEVERE
oracle.sql.level=FINE
oracle.net.level=SEVERE
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=CONFIG
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=c:/Workpath/java/jdbc%u%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=5
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

I repeat, i have no problem to run the test with the two ojdbc_g drivers. The problem is in the output file log, the ojdbc8_g hasn't the stack trace information that is written by the ojdbc7_g. I need to use the ojdbc8_g for one particular customer that is unable to use the ojdbc7_g.

Comment: Could your provide a [mre] that works with ojdbc7 (and specify the full version please), but doesn't work with ojdbc8 (also specify the full version)?

Comment: the full version of drivers are ojdbc7_g.jar and ojdbc8_g.jar. These are the diagnostic library for to get the informations of the SQL executed. I didn't post example beacuse i used common configuration -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Workpath/java/log.properties -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true
If you execute one class that make query on oracle db one log is generated. My problem is that with ojdbc7_g in the log there is the stack trace of that SQL. With ojdbc8_g the stack trace on the log is missing

Comment: No, ojdbc7 indicates it's for Java 7, while ojdbc8 indicates it's for Java 8. It is not the version of the library.

Comment: Ah okay, now i got what you were asking, the version used is Java 8 and each of ojdbc7_g and ojdbc8_g work with Java 8, the difference could be in Oracle Version where ojdbc8 is needed for 12.2 and major if i remember right. In my test the oracle version is 12.1 and is compatible with the two jdbc drivers

Comment: There are a lot of different versions of ojdbc7_g and ojdbc8_g. Which version specifically are you using?

Comment: For the ojdbc8_g i'm using this one: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html under the diagnosibility related ojdbc8-diag.tar.gz.
For the ojdbc7_g i'm using this one https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-upc-downloads.html, always under the diagnosability the related ojdbc-diag.tar.gz  
I confirm you that i am using these two driver without any problem on the same target database version, the problem is the log generated that with the ojdbc8_g.jar i have no stack trace on the log

Comment: So, that is odjbc8_g 12.2.0.1 and ojdbc7_g 12.1.0.2.

Comment: Yes right, but why do you closed the question? I provided everything is needed and detailed in every mode possible the situation and the output